# DataGridView skip Column from Updating

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

Is there any possibility to skip or delete specific column of `DataGridView` from updating to the database?

I need to prevent column from updating to the database, because the column values is encrypted and when I decrypt, the decrypted values updated to the database.

I used this code before, but this really slows the grid.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
     if (hide == false && e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
     {
         e.Value = Decrypt(e.Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Updating values with this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();

    if (changes != null)
    {
        MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
        mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();

        mySqlDataAdapter.Update(changes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there is, just set `ReadOnly` property of the column of `DataGridView` to `true`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have Column with encrypted values what i need to decrypt but when the values is decrypted and other cell is edited i dont want to update the decrypted values to the database only the edited cell value.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I need to prevent column from updating to the database, because the column values is encrypted and when i decrypt, the decrypted values updated to the database.

Comment: Based on the new edition of your question, You can add another unbound column to `DataGridView` and show decrypted content in the new unbound column and just hide the encrypted column.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I try this

Comment: @RezaAghaei I create the new column and get the old column values in array but the populate not working for the new column.

Comment: You don't need an array @X11. Follow the way you were doing the task. Using a `CellFormatting` method you can simply provide value for the cell. It's enough to check if the column index is for your new column, then decrypt the value of that old hidden column and set as e.Value.

Comment: I always get the error, data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: I have no idea about your encryption and decryption algorithm. But I can suppose you have a `string Decrypt(string value){return "something";}`. Also I can suppose you have a column "A" which contains encrypted value and you want it to be hidden in grid, but you want to have a column "B" that shows decrypted value of "A" in it. Then the user can change other fields except "A" and "B". Then you want to save the values to database.

Comment: If this is your question, you can reword your question and add enough description which shows the situation like I described and then if you yourself couldn't solve the problem based on above comments, I'll share an answer for you. My answer would contain also some codes to show decrypted value in "B" column. Let me know if such answer would be acceptable and useful for you :)

Comment: i dont want to save A and B Column i just want to read the B Column if A Column is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what the title is saying, it's enough to set `ReadOnly` property of the column to true, but since you want to show decrypted value of the column in your grid, to prevent the column from being updated in database, you can use either of these options:

- Show encrypted value in the column itself and change your update command to not contain statement for updating that specific column.
- You can show the encrypted value in another unbound column.

In this post I show you an example of the second solution.

I suppose you have a `string Decrypt(string value)` method which decrypts an encrypted string. Also I can you have a column "A" which contains encrypted value and as the question you want to show decrypted value in a "B" column in grid.

So perform these steps:

- Set `Visible` property of "A" column to `false`.
- Add a `DataGridViewTextBox` column and set its name to "B"
- Handle `CellFormatting` event of `DtaGridView` like below:

```
private void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex<0 || e.RowIndex<0)
        return;

    var columnB = grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (columnB.Name != "B")
        return;

    var value = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["A"].Value;
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return;

    cell.Value = Decrypt(value.ToString());
}
```

**Note**

- It's not good idea to save changes on after you leave row. It's better to save changes after the edit is finished by click on a Save button.
- You don't need to call `AcceptChanges`. In fact you should not!
- Usually its enough to set `cell.Value = Decrypt(value.ToString());`but since you may have performance issues by `Decrypt`, Instead of setting `e.Value` you can check if the cell doesn't have value, will set the value for cell:

  ```
  var cell = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["B"];
  if (cell.Value== null || cell.Value == DBNull.Value)
  {
      cell.Value = Decrypt(value.ToString());
  }
  ```
- Please pay attention to the warning which is in 
  remarks section of the [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) event: *`CellFormatting` event occurs every time each cell is painted, so
  you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event.*

Comment: It works, but have the same performance issue while scrolling.

Comment: btw. i try to set A Column Visible to false and get the Decrypted A Column values to B Column with this code: dataGridView1["B", i].Value = Decrypt(dataGridView1["A", i].Value.ToString()); but this code does not populate the B Column.

Comment: Check the Edit.Usually its enough to set `cell.Value = Decrypt(value.ToString());` but since you may have performance issues by `Decrypt` I check if the cell doesn't have value, will set the value for cell.

Comment: To make a column Invisible use such code `grid.Columns["A"].Visible = false;`

Comment: By the way, just test the solution in a clean environment. I believe performance issues are not related to this question and you should keep a question only related to a single issue. Is you had some other issues, feel free to ask another question :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about applying the solution or if you find it useful :)

Comment: Your edited code not working for me, it does not set the values in the B Column and slows more the gridview.

Comment: No problem, use the previous version and ask a new question about performance. It works in a clean environment well.

Comment: It seems the post answers your question. When you find a post useful, you can vote for it by click on up arrow. Also if it solves the problem (which I believe it does) you can click on check-mark to mark it as accepted. But it's not compulsory at all :)

Comment: Probably yes. The current solution which comes to my mind is setting the value as above. But some other options are possible too, for example adding the column to a `DataTable` and set those values once in a loop.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at this post [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).